# How to mock static object inside an Interface by using JUnit5 in Java?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, powermock

Currently I am using JUnit5 for creating test cases in Java. But in some places I could not implement the test cases due to Mock issue.

This is my interface:

```
public interface EntityLookup extends Lookup {

  public static final Constants constants = new Constants();
  
  public static class Constants {

    public EntityLookup VERIFY;
    
    public void initialize() {

      this.VERIFY = (EntityLookup)LookupHelper.getLookupInstance(EntityLookup.class, "ABCD");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to mock the below code

```
EntityLookup.constants.VERIFY.trimmedValue()
```

I know how to implement in JUnit4

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(EntityLookup.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(EntityLookup.Constants.class);
    
    EntityLookup.Constants constants = Mockito.mock(EntityLookup.Constants.class);
    
    EntityLookup entityLookup = Mockito.mock(EntityLookup.class);
    
    PowerMockito.whenNew(EntityLookup.Constants.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(constants);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(EntityLookup.constants, "VERIFY", entityLookup);
    Mockito.when(entityLookup.trimmedValue()).thenReturn("ABCD");

    //assert...
  }
}
```

**But in JUnit5, I have no idea**

Can anyone convert it to JUnit5 from JUnit4?

Comment: `EntityLookup.Constants.VERIFY = mock(…)`? It's public, so you should be able to simply assign a new value to the field

Comment: @knittl +1 but be careful when running tests concurrently. Then, tests using `EntityLookup` should at least define a corresponding [`@ResourceLock`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution-synchronization).